# "if" condition ignored in "for"

Tags: c, database, loops, for-loop

I have a code where I pull data from a DB according to the DB ID.

When I use the loop for my if condition is being ignored and the code always runs even if equals.

I made two examples showing the use of for and another showing only if check.

Using the if only check, the code works, but I need the use of for because DB has a lot of entries.

DB Entries:

```
0,2115
1,604
2,254
3,425
4,321
5,98
6,15001
...
```

Code for:

```
int use_sm(struct session *ss, int n) {
    struct db_sm *sm = sm->database(ss->get_sm);

    if (!sm)
        return 1;

    if (sm->enable && sm->count_db > 0) {
        struct get_dfs *gf = ss->data[n];

        if (gf) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sm->count_db; i++) {
                if(gf->u_id != sm->db[i].u_id) { //code is running even though ==
                    printf("u_id %d db_u_id %d\n", gf->u_id, sm->db[i].u_id);
                    sm->use_sm_sub(sm, 5);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Code if:

```
int use_sm(struct session *ss, int n) {
    struct db_sm *sm = sm->database(ss->get_sm);

    if (!sm)
        return 1;

    if (sm->enable && sm->count_db > 0) {
        struct get_dfs *gf = ss->data[n];

        if (gf) {
            if (gf->u_id != sm->db[0].u_id && gf->u_id != sm->db[1].u_id && gf->u_id != sm->db[2].u_id && gf->u_id != sm->db[3].u_id) {
                printf("u_id %d u_id1 %d u_id2 %d u_id3 %d u_id4 %d\n", gf->u_id, sm->db[0].u_id, sm->db[1].u_id, sm->db[2].u_id, sm->db[3].u_id);
                sm->use_sm_sub(sm, 5);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Code using **if** condition works correctly.
When if verifies that ***gf->u_id*** value is **==** ***sm->db[x].u_id*** the code is not executed.

What is wrong with the for loop?

Comment: If the code is not executed, then it's something wrong with your compiler. That's very unlikely. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @klutt I'm using visual studio, I only have problem in this part, I have other ties that work correctly

Comment: As I said, please fix a [mre]. I voted to close this question since I cannot reprocude the error.

Comment: Is there any way to apply this in the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` tests multiple conditions with `&&` and one false condition results in the entire `if` being false.
The `for` iterates and tests one condition multiple times and the block executes for each true condition.
Use a flag to find a match and skip printing when the flag is set.

```
int use_sm(struct session *ss, int n) {
    struct db_sm *sm = sm->database(ss->get_sm);

    if (!sm)
        return 1;

    if (sm->enable && sm->count_db > 0) {
        struct get_dfs *gf = ss->data[n];
        if (gf) {
            int match = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sm->count_db; i++) {
                if(gf->u_id == sm->db[i].u_id) {
                    match = 1;//found a match
                }
            }
            if ( ! match) {//no matches
                printf("u_id %d ", gf->u_id);
                for (int i = 0; i < sm->count_db; i++) {
                    printf("db[%d].u_id %d ", i, sm->db[i].u_id);
                }
                printf("\n");
                sm->use_sm_sub(sm, 5);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the top one you have

```
if (gf) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sm->count_db; i++) {
        if(gf->nameid...
```

One the bottom one you have

```
if (gf->u_id...
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, I changed by unintentionally formatting code to post. I'm using `gf->u_id`